# Selenium IDE does not record autocalculation

Tags: selenium, ide

OK, so I have a form.
I enter numeric value in one text box, and at the same time system calculates and displays value in a second (read only) text box. When I record it with IDE, second text box is left with no value.

When I say "at the same time" I mean when I enter "1" in text_box_1, text_box_2 displays "1" simultaneously. Those are just sample numbers, however, that's how it works in application.

If anyone could give me a direction on how can I make sure that IDE records what displays in text_box_2, I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the second box is most likely being written to via some javascript updater. In order to get this to work you may have to use Selenium WebDriver's 'SendKeys' which will actually simulate typing into the box. I'm unsure why IDE's typing doesn't do this but the idea is to trigger a javascript 'update' or 'change' event so that it will populate the text in the second box. If this doesn't work you can also aim to manually call the javascript update; though this isn't the recommended approach.
I don't use the IDE so potentially someone will have a better solution, but I suggest if you are getting into this sort of testing you might want to consider moving to WebDriver (but this purely my opinion! :)).

Comment: Thanks Nashibukasan,

You are correct. There is a javascript function that gets triggered to calculate the value in field 2. Would you know how to trigger it manually from within an IDE? 
I am just starting to implement automation and taking small steps starting with IDE. WebDriver is in my future and once I get comfortable with IDE, I think I will move towards its implementation.
Thanks!

Comment: I actually never used the IDE! But WebDriver is very good at triggering events via interaction with the UI. I have not had to call javascript very often in Selenium. Glad I helped :)